# IText special character encoding

Tags: xslt, encoding, itext

I'm having what I believe is something related to encoding in IText.

I developed a report in xsl and want to print some special characters from a custom .otf file.

First the .xsl code

```
<span class="symbol card-logo">&#xf000;</span>
```

After that the .xsl code is converted to a HTML. The HTML code works fine in the browsers, with all the characters that I want. But after that I pass the HTML String to the ITextRenderer.

```
ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
renderer.getFontResolver().addFont(otfFile.getAbsolutePath(), BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
byte[] bytes = htmlDocumentString.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");

ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();

InputSource is = new InputSource(bais);
Document doc = builder.parse(is);

renderer.setDocument(doc, null);

renderer.layout();
renderer.createPDF(outputStream);
outputStream.flush();
outputStream.close();
```

I almost solved the problem when I added the `BaseFont.IDENTITY_H`, while adding the fonts to the renderer, but then another character disappeared from the report (the `&#8482;` - trademark logo)

The weird part: 
With the code like this I the trademark logo is actually printed if, and only if, the `&#xf000;` character is printed anywhere in the report. Otherwise it only prints it's "space".
Also, if I don't add the `BaseFont.IDENTITY_H`, the trademark logo works fine, but the `&#xf000;` doesn't.

I hope this is not too much confuse!

It seems like when the `&#xf000;` character is printed it stretches the "character window" so then the trademark logo is printed fine. But I'm not sure of this.

```
&#xf000 - icon;
&#8482 - company logo
```

Answer (score 0):

How about adding a bunch of whitespace at the bottom and then letting a cropper - client side - remove the whitespace?

That's how I would solve it.